# Do user controlled CSS selectors need to be sanitized?

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

Can a user controlled CSS selector be abused? If so how should it be sanitized?

Specifically, in this case, I am using the selector with jQuery in the following manner `$('a').not(userSuppliedSelector)`, but I am also interested in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you actually inject the selector into a css file and don't sanitize at a user could insert any css and completely change the look of the website. This would work similarly to a SQL injection.

If you just use the selector like in the example no such things can happen. The user just has control over which links get selected. Just don't put an eval around the string ;). Bad selectors can lead to bad performance though.

How you get the value is also important. Just as an example, if you were to get a selector from a url parameter and just inject it in a css file someone could create a url that could change how your page looks like (while keeping the certificate and base url) and then attempt to phish your users by sending them the link.

But sanitization is probably a good idea anyways.

Comment: Great. Sanitize it just in case? I suppose that helps protect against bugs and discoveries. Any chance you have a preferred CSS sanitizer?

Comment: but you could have a list of accepted chars (*, :, A-Za-z, ...) and cut the string when one different char is used.